# In Gnome file browser, fall back to the parent directory when a directory is deleted

Tags: gnome, nautilus, file-browser

I am using CentOS Release 6.4(Final), with Kernel Linux 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64, and GNOME 2.82.2.

I have enabled “Always open in browser” option in the File management preferences. I have a script running that prints the log in a directory. If the script processing is successful, the script also deletes the logs and their directory. The logs and the directory are not deleted if script processing fails.

Now when I have opened the log directory and the script terminates successfully (so the directory is deleted), the whole browser is closed (along with all tabs it have!) rather than falling back to the parent directory (expected behavior).

Is there any setting that will prevent the Gnome file browser from  closing and make it fall back to its parent directory?